# Loading the Output of XmlSerializer into an XmlDictionaryReader

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, filestream

I am facing this problem

```
class person
{
;
}

person p = new person();
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(p.GetType());
FileStream fs = File.Open("sam.xml",FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

ser.Serialize(fs,p)

fs.flush();
fs.close();

FileStream stream = FileStream("sam.xml", FileMode.Open);
XmlDictionaryReader xdr = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(stream,new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
```

now my problem is how can i create xdr object without creating xml files.

Comment: What do you plan to do with the `XmlDictionaryReader`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a memory stream like that:

```
class person 
{ 
; 
} 

person p = new person(); 
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())     
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(p.GetType()); 
    ser.Serialize(ms,p) 

    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 

    XmlDictionaryReader xdr = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(ms,new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
}
```

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

Serialize to a memorystream instead of a filestream.

Comment: I am getting System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected end of file. error at XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(ms, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas) .\

Comment: You'll need tyo seek the stream back to the beginning.